# QT Deploy to windows from linux (manjaro)

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I've been trying to figure out how i'm supposed to generate a .exe using qt creator for hours now.

I read about the `windeployqt` tool but the only thing i found in my qt installation similar to this is a `windeployqt.prf`, and i have no idea how to use this. I also can't find any sources to download, even from source.

I'd like to make a static build to avoid any DLL issues but i can't find any instructions on how to do it and the documentation is not helpful.

If you have a step by step guide or ressource that explains how to do that i'll be greatful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Qt static linking and deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011197/qt-static-linking-and-deployment)

Comment: See if these help: [Deploy Qt to Windows on a Linux machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69441450/deploy-qt-to-windows-on-a-linux-machine), [How to release a Qt/C++ application on Linux and Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49982419/how-to-release-a-qt-c-application-on-linux-and-windows)

Comment: Just to be clear: so you want ro *cross-compile* on Linux host for Windows target? Not supported.

Answer (score 1):

In a normal Qt installation, `windeployqt.exe` is in `${QT_INSTALL_DIR}/your_version/your_compiler/bin`

For instance, if you installed Qt in `C:\Qt` and you are using Qt 6.3 with mingw_64, the path is `C:\Qt\6.3.0\mingw_64\bin`.

As for usual, cross compiling is **not** supported. You need to compile your application on Windows to have a Windows executable. If you still want to cross compile, have a look at [CQtDeployer](https://github.com/QuasarApp/CQtDeployer).

Comment: forgot to mention i'm on manjaro, windeployqt is NOT installed

Comment: I'll look into CQtDeployer since i'm trying to do cross compilation.

Comment: @Shyne windeployqt can't be installed on linux, as far as I know